# Can't install bson_ext gem, but other gems install just fine

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Driving me crazy here.  I can't install the bson_ext gem.  I'm on a very clean Windows VM with RubyInstaller and DevKit set up just fine.

```
C:\DevKit>gem install bson_ext
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for asprintf()... no
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for ruby/regex.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating cbson-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bson_buffer.c
compiling cbson.c
cbson.c:25:23: fatal error: arpa/inet.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [cbson.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bson_ext-
1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bson_ext-1.11.1/ext/cbson/
gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue with Ruby 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got mine working.

Try this in the order that I did it:

Delete the basic Gem file (under \lib\ruby)
Reinstall all other gems besides mongo and bson_ext
Run command 'gem install mongo -v=1.9'
Run command 'gem install bson_ext -v=1.9.2'

Now, try running the command and see if it works for ya

Comment: Sorry - which file do I delete?  I only see four subfolders under \lib\ruby (they are 1.9.1, gems, site_ruby, and vendor_ruby)

Comment: Luckily this looks like this is no longer an issue with Ruby 2.1